# How do I comprehend the 'all' concept in 'git push --all' and simply 'git push' but push.defaults configured to be 'matching' respectively?

Tags: git, git-push, git-config

I am having a bit of a hard time figuring out what the question title suggests. Basically, `git push --all`(or maybe less often `git push --all <remote>`) and simply `git push` but defaulted to 'matching' both give a reference to 'all'.

I did some research over this, but most of what I found was simply the effects of each command respectively, and didn't find anything that has them both in mind. So I was wondering if they have nothing to do with each other at all, or there is indeed overlap and some interplay when they are present together at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Obviously they don't have "nothing to do with each other", since, as the docs say, "the whole point of this mode is to allow you to push all of the branches in one go"

Comment: From the docs, `When the command line does not specify what to push with <refspec>... arguments or --all, --mirror, --tags options, the command finds the default <refspec> by consulting remote.*.push configuration, and if it is not found, honors push.default configuration to decide what to push (See git-config[1] for the meaning of push.default).` , my best guess is when '--all' is present, the defaults are just ignored. (I think almost no one has ever run into a scenario like this, simply because the combos themselves each are very rarely people's preferences, let alone combined)

Comment: "my best guess is when '--all' is present, the defaults are just ignored" Really? Okay, let's do a little thought experiment. You say `git push --all`. And let's pretend the configurations are ignored. Now tell me: how does Git decide what remote branch to push each local branch to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall `git push` command is:

```
git push [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec> ...]]
```

That is, there are optional *options*, such as `--all`, `-n`, `--tags`, and so on.  You may use one, or some in combination, or none, as documented.  All the options start with `-` to distinguish them from the remaining arguments.

The remaining arguments are, in order:

- the repository, then
- the refspec(s).

If you give *no* additional arguments (besides options) you have not provided a *`repository`* argument, and if you give only one additional argument (besides options) you have supplied a *`repository`* but no *`refspec`*.

The `--all` flag is a way of writing the refspec `refs/heads/*`, without typing in `refs/heads/*` as a *`refspec`*.  The fact that you don't have to type it in as a refspec frees you from the obligation to provide a *`repository`*.  Other than this particular freedom, plus one more constraint, that's *all* `--all` means.

(The extra constraint is that if you do use `--all` you are not *allowed* to use a *`refspec`*.)

Since `--all` just implies one particular refspec, the rest of the documentation can be read *as if* you had run:

```
git push <repository> "refs/heads/*"
```

for some *`repository`* argument.  Adding other options such as `--dry-run` has the effect listed for that option.

> [What if] `push.defaults` [is] configured to be 'matching'?

The `push.defaults` setting takes effect if you provide *no* refspec arguments.  Since `--all` effectively *does* provide a refspec argument, it is ignored if you use `--all`.  If you *do not* use `--all` ***and** do not* provide a refspec, your `push.default` setting goes into effect.

Comment: Thanks you for you detailed answer coz that explains a lot. Also I can think of `git push origin :`. Do you think it is (almost) the equivalent of `push.default` of 'matching'?

Comment: `git push origin :` *is* a "matching" push (to `origin`), yes. You could equivalently run `git -c push.default=matching push origin` (but that requires typing in more stuff and is harder to understand in the first place, so I'd normally use the `:` refspec directly).

Comment: Note that `matching` and `--all` differ in that `--all` pushes *your* heads, not the *matching* heads. Suppose you have `a`, `b`, and `c`, and they have `b`, `c`, and `d`: `git push --all origin` pushes your `a` (plus b and c) but `git push origin :` pushes only b and c (because they lack `a`).